# JTabe selecting / highlighting row(s) by pressing a key on keyboard

Tags: java, select, keyboard, jtable, highlight

I have a JTable with actually 4 columns and many rows. Now i want to select one or more rows by pressig a key on the keyboard. But i have no idea how do that.

This is the example of what i want:

- if i press "F" on keyboard my application should select or hightlight the first row in my table which has an entry beginning with the char "F" (or the other i pressed
- if i press the same key again (here "F"), then is should select or highlight te next row which has an entry beginning with the char "F"
- if the last row is selected and i press the same key again it should select or highlight the first row again (looping)
- when i press another key, for example "U", it should do the same with the rows beginning with "U" like above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounded like an interesting problem. So I hacked up something which can be the basis of your solution. Note: You can improve this further with proper encapsulation and generics.
Warning : use this only if your table data model is small. If it is big you should consider some better approach for search as well as concurrency/UI feedback to avoid freezing of your UI.
Anyway, the solution will be in similar lines as below. The key is to add a key listener to the table, and then checking key press character against row/col values. HTH

```
package example;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

/** Extend default model to make cells non-editable */
class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
    public MyTableModel(Object[][] data, Object[] headers) {
        super(data, headers);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }
}

/** Key listener that controls row highlighting */
class SearchingKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
    private final JTable table;
    private int selectedRow = -1;//before start

    public SearchingKeyAdapter(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        String keyChar = String.valueOf(e.getKeyChar());
        TableModel model = table.getModel();
        int startRow = selectedRow;
        if (selectedRow == model.getRowCount() - 1) {
            startRow = -1;//Go before start
        }
        //Check each cell to see if it starts with typed char.
        //if so set corresponding row selected and return.
        for (int row = startRow+1; row < model.getRowCount(); row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < model.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                String value = (String) model.getValueAt(row, col);
                if (value != null && value.startsWith(keyChar)) {
                    table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                    table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                    table.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
                    selectedRow = row;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

public class App {
    JFrame frame;
    JTable table;
    String[][] data = {
            {"for", "util", "synchronized", "final"}, {"finally", "throw", "throws", "try"}, {"import", "class", "interface", "if"}, {"public", "private", "protected", "volatile"}
    };
    String[] headers = {"Keyword1", "Keyword2", "Keyword3", "Keyword3"};

    public App() {
        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new MyTableModel(data, headers));
        //Add special key listener that will move highlight based on typed char
        table.addKeyListener(new SearchingKeyAdapter(table));
        //We need to have only single selection
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.getViewport().add(table);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                App app = new App();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks fo the help. i tried it with you code and for my actual table it works nearly i want it. But one problem is: when i sort my table by clicking on one of my tableHeader Columns your code stop to work. And one other issuer i noticed is: when i don't select any row and sort the table it will select the rows, but the false ones, so the tableDataModel or something is incorrect to the selection it makes :( Can you add the piece of code i need, that it works, when i sort my table, too? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Hi, Please note that when you sort you are meddling with the model itself. So likely the selectedRow variable value becomes invalid in that context. Purpose of the code was to show how this can be achieved, and it does not cover all the use-cases. It would be worthwhile for you to try and figure this out.